Calculating volume of convex set (references)
I would like to find a reference for this property in relation to calculating volume:
Let $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be convex. We can approximate the volume of $K$ by counting the volume of small cubes with vertices at points of the refined lattice $(\frac{1}{k} \mathbb{Z})^{n}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
    V_n(K)&=&\int_{K} d\mathbf{x}\\&=&\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{1}{k^n} \#(K \cap \frac {1}{k}\mathbb Z^{n})\\
    &=& \lim_{k\to \infty} \frac{1}{k^n} \#(k\cdot K \cap \mathbb Z^{n}).
   \end{eqnarray*}

Isn't this pretty close to integrating the indicator function?
